# Second Hard drive does not appear in the Ubuntu installer, "Installation Type" screen

Tags: installation, 13.10, hard-drive, drive

I have two hard drives installed on my laptop.  One has Windows 8.1 installed and I want to put Ubuntu (13.10) on the second drive.

I partitioned 200GB of space from the second drive.

When the installation reaches the "Installation Type" portion, I only see the Windows drive. "/dev/sda".  I do not see the second drive.  How can I remedy this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try fixparts,to fix the drives not seen during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to install ubuntu not alongside with Windows, so base on the installation instruction stated [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest), on step no.4 choose 'Something else', step no.5 you can select the 2nd hard drive by choosing it in 'Select drive' tab.

hope this helps